# Javascript create array from local words.txt 2021

Tags: javascript

I have a txt file called test.txt.

Inside of it there are words that are basically laid out like this.

```
ability
able
about
above
accept
according
account
across
act
action
activity
actually
add
address
administration
admit
adult
affect
after
again
against
age
agency
agent
ago
```

I want to use these words turn them into an array and store into one variable.

Something like this.

var words = ["ability", "about", "above", "action"...];

I am only using javascript and nothing else how do I do this?

Comment: What have you tried yourself..‍♂️

Comment: Are you using a form to get your file or do you pass the path to it yourself, i.e. it is a local file?

Comment: First, which platform your program will be running on?
If your program is running in the browser, you need to study how to use ajax to get the file from a server.

If your program is running on the desktop, you need to study how to use node js to read and write a file.

Comment: JS can't read user computer files, how you going to feed this file to JS? Ajax, input field, etc.?

Comment: Hi @SudarZGracer are you using NodeJS or really just javascript ?

Comment: I am running tis on the browser I haven't tried ajax since that is jquery I assume. I think I will need to use node js.

Comment: You can also use <input type="file" /> and FileReader from browser

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using node.js since you are accessing a file.

```
const fs = require('fs');
let array = fs.readFile('./test.txt').split(/\r?\n/g);
```

Otherwise the answer is: JavaScript is executed client-side and won't handle files.

Comment: oh, okay. i see.

Comment: thanks. seems like I wasted a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
file.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/g)
```

Comment: file is not defined

Comment: I know... I first thought that you have your file...